# PDE with Stochastic Coefficients

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus

Does anyone have reference suggestions for pde's with stochastic coefficients?

I've seen many papers on more advanced problems, but it would be great to have a reference discussing the basic theory and the differences between pde, pde with stochastic coefficients, and stochastic pde.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Could you give an example of a pde with stochastic coefficients?

Comment: By application of Feynman-Kak theorem we change SDE to PDE. and there is not stochastic PDE's with stochastic coefficients in finance or stochastic analyses or Mechanic Quantum.

Comment: @Ant $\partial_t u + a(t, \omega) \partial_x u = 0$, where $a(t, \omega)$ is random.

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki I'm not sure I understand your statement. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @Ant there is several example :$$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}}+W_t\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{S_t}}=0$$ where $W_t$ is Brownian motion but what is it's application?

Comment: Where we apply PDE with Stochastic Coefficients?

Comment: Any application, just looking for any reference.

Comment: Check models in finance with stochastic volatility eg Heston model Sabr model